# why my button still has padding android

Tags: android, button, padding

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProfileUpdatePhotoSave"
        style="@style/profile_update_photo_button"
        android:text="@string/profile_update_photo_save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProfileUpdatePhotoCancel"
        style="@style/profile_update_photo_button"
        android:text="@string/profile_update_photo_cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

with this style:

```
<style name="profile_update_photo_button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo_text_color</item>
</style>
```

both `layout_width` and `layout_height` are `wrap_content`. However, while there are no padding to the buttons in its sides (hence I put `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft`) there is significant padding from top and buttom (like 10dp or something like that).

The `@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo` basically hold rectangle shape with 5dp rounded corners.

How can I get rid from this padding?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the padding for top and bottom to zero or some other value, use

```
android:paddingBottom
```

> Sets the padding, in pixels, of the bottom edge.

or

```
android:paddingTop
```

> Sets the padding, in pixels, of the top edge

You will have to add those items to your `<style>`.

```
<style name="profile_update_photo_button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: sorry guys, I forgot to mention that I tried it, of course. but with no success. the button can have 0dp padding from left and right, but still has very noticeable padding from top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Define top and bottom padding values in your style to go with your left and right values.  If left unspecified, you'll get the default padding for the control.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is setting the minimal height

```
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Just add these to your style

```
<style name="profile_update_photo_button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/custom_button_profile_update_photo_text_color</item>
<item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you